# "Unresolved compilation problems" with Maven multi-module EAR files

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-3

The JSP's in the war module won't compile because the jar module isn't on the classpath when they are compiled.

EAR module dependencies

```
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <artifactId>rtuDataAccess</artifactId>
   <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
   <version>${project.version}</version>
   <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <artifactId>rtu</artifactId>
   <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
   <version>${project.version}</version>
   <type>war</type>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <artifactId>rtuEformProcess</artifactId>
   <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
   <version>${project.version}</version>
   <type>war</type>
  </dependency>

 </dependencies>
```

EAR plugin setup

```
    <plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4.2</version>

<configuration>
    <defaultJavaBundleDir>lib/</defaultJavaBundleDir>
 <modules>
  <jarModule>
   <groupId>edu.mayo.lpea.lsa</groupId>
   <artifactId>rtuDataAccess</artifactId>
  </jarModule>

  <webModule>
   <groupId>edu.mayo.lpea.lsa</groupId>
   <artifactId>rtu</artifactId>
   <contextRoot>/lsa/rtu</contextRoot>
  </webModule>
  <webModule>
   <groupId>edu.mayo.lpea.lsa</groupId>
   <artifactId>rtuEformProcess</artifactId>
   <contextRoot>/lsa/rtuEformProcess</contextRoot>
  </webModule>
 </modules>
</configuration>
```

WAR plugin (in war module)

```
       <plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
                <ignoreWebxml>true</ignoreWebxml>
                <archive>
                   <manifest>
                       <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                       <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                   </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
```

Comment: maven war plugin does not do compilation. Perhaps you should snippet of the pom which builds the war.

Comment: The error occurs when the JSPs are compiled by the application server.  Apparently the JAR isn't being put on the class path for this compilation.  The JAR and WAR files look fine.

Comment: edu.mayo.lpea.lsa.jar is missing from dependencies

Comment: What application server are you deploying too?